# Why map {}.compact is faster than each_with_object([])?

Tags: ruby

I did some benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'

words = File.open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line.take(1_000_000).map(&:chomp)
end

Benchmark.bmbm(20) do |x|
  GC.start
  x.report(:map) do
    words.map do |word|
      word.size if word.size > 5
    end.compact
  end

  GC.start
  x.report(:each_with_object) do
    words.each_with_object([]) do |word, long_sizes|
      long_sizes << word.size if word.size > 5
    end
  end
end
```

Output (ruby 2.3.0):

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------------
map                    0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.016906)
each_with_object       0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.024695)
----------------------------------------------- total: 0.040000sec

                           user     system      total        real
map                    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.015004)
each_with_object       0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.024183)
```

I cannot understand it because I thought that `each_with_object` should be faster: it needs only 1 loop and 1 new object to create a new array instead of 2 loops and 2 new objects in case when we combine `map` and `compact`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Because `long_words << word` causes memory allocations from time to time

Comment: It's a time-memory tradeoff: `map` / `compact` is faster but uses more memory, whereas `each_with_object` is slower but consumes less memory.

Comment: Note that `words.select { |word| word.size > 5 }` is shorter, more logical and faster than both your examples.

Comment: @EricDuminil, of course, it's obvious. The instance is just for benchmarking. I edited the question, so now your comment is not relevant.

Comment: You got me : `words.map{|w| w.size }.select{|s| s > 5}` is slower than your methods :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Array#<<` needs to reallocate memory if the original memory space doesn't have enough room to hold the new item. See [the implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), especially this line

```
VALUE target_ary = ary_ensure_room_for_push(ary, 1);
```

While `Array#map` doesn't have to reallocate memory from time to time because it already knows the size of the result array. See [the implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map), especially

```
collect = rb_ary_new2(RARRAY_LEN(ary));
```

which allocates the same size of memory as the original array.